# Need help on traversing DOM elements and return an object representing the form structure and values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, object

// Write a function that takes form id as input, and returns an object representing the form structure and values.

```
 <pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="form1" ><input type="text" name="foo.bar" value="test1" /></form>
        <form id="form2" >
          <input type="text" name="foo.bar" />
          <input type="text" name="foo.baz.qux" value="test2" />
          <input type="text" name="qux" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
    </pre>
```

///// Expected result/////

// When calling the function with 'form1', expect the following object result

```
expect(result).toEqual({
  foo: {
    bar: 'test1',
  }
});
```

// When calling the function with 'form2', expect the following object result

```
expect(result).toEqual({
  foo: {
    bar: '',
    baz: {
      qux: 'test2',
    }
  },
  qux: '',
});
```

// Solution which i've tried is,

```
const Forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
const inputs = [...Forms[0]];

const result = {};

inputs.forEach(input => {
  // console.log("Outer", input.name);
  const val = input.value;
  const arrOfName = input.name.split('.');
  
  let prev = arrOfName[0];
  arrOfName.forEach((n, idx) => {
    let len = arrOfName.length;
    console.log("n", n, "idx", idx,"prev", prev);
    // if(idx < len) {
      console.log("idx", idx, "prev", prev, "res", result, "current", n, "IS", !result[n]);
      if(!result[n]) {
         result[n] = {};
         prev = n;
      } else {
        result[prev][n] = {};
        prev = result[prev][n];
        console.log("result[prev]", result[prev])
      }

    console.log("Result:", result);
  })
});
```

// Any idea on how to make preserve previously updated key and update new key under it for that same iteration.
// TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works. As you said it, need to preserve the previously updated key in a variable.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const inputs = [...form];

var result = {}
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  var name = input.name
  var value = input.value

  var arr = name.split(".");
  var obj = result;
  var last = obj;
  var last_key = name
  arr.forEach(function(name) {
    obj[name] = obj[name] || {}
    last = obj;
    last_key = name;
    obj = obj[name]
  })
  last[last_key] = value;
})


console.log(result)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="foo.bar" />
    <input type="text" name="foo.baz.qux" value="test2" />
    <input type="text" name="qux" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot IT goldman. It really helped me. You really did it in no time. Great.